# I can't install dkms Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dkms

I'm getting this error while installing dkms

```
sudo apt-get install dksm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
E: Unable to locate package dkmms
```

Comment: Please check your text for typos because you have dkms, dksm and dkmms in it.

Answer (score 1):

To install `dkms`, the package for Dynamic Kernel Module Support Framework you should run the following in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

This package is readily available in Trusty:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ apt-cache policy dkms
dkms:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.7
  Version table:
     2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.7 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
andrew@corinth:~$
```

There is of course no such packages as `dksm` which I assume is a glorious typo :)

Comment: sudo apt-get install dkms    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package dkms is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate

Comment: I didn't realize there was a typo in my post, thanks for pointing that out. Using the correct command still reports the same output

Comment: Do a `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install dkms`. Cheers, Al

Comment: Yep, already sudo apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. It doesn't seem like the repo is installed, however it is. Is there a manual source to get this from? I was thinking about the .deb file from Debian, however I am not sure about compatibility issues being that it isn't from the repositories.